# PHP Exec function reports failure on some commands that work by SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, php

I'm on CentOS 6 64bit with PHP 5.4.12.

This is very strange behavior by PHP.

See the following script:

```
echo 'Trying Query: whereis jbig2dec<br>';
exec('whereis jbig2dec',$output) or die('Failed');

$location=explode(' ',implode($output));
$location=$location[1];

echo 'Result: '.implode($output)."<p>";

echo 'Trying Query: '.$location.' --help<br>';
exec($location.' --help',$output) or die('Failed');

echo 'Result: '.implode($output)."<p>";

echo 'Trying Query: jbig2dec --help<br>';
exec('jbig2dec --help',$output) or die('Failed');

echo 'Result: '.implode($output)."<p>";
```

The result is:

```
Trying Query: whereis jbig2dec
Result: jbig2dec: /usr/local/bin/jbig2dec
Trying Query: /usr/local/bin/jbig2dec --help
Failed
```

Basically you can see above that PHP exec function works for `whereis jbig2dec` but fails for `/usr/local/bin/jbig2dec --help`. BUT if I type `/usr/local/bin/jbig2dec --help` or `jbig2dec --help` into SSH I get the correct response from jbig2dec.

How could this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the return value of `/usr/local/bin/jbig2dec --help` over SSH like this:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/jbig2dec --help
[... generates some output ...]
$ echo $?
```

The last command prints the "return value" of the previous call. A return value of `0` is "the shell way" of saying "the command executed successfully". A return value of something else indicates an error.

If `exec()` encounters a return value that is not 0 (which some programs give on help messages, since the program did not technically run), it will return "false" in the PHP context and thus trigger the `or die()` part and terminate the PHP script with the given error message.

In shorter words: your command probably does not return a successful status, and you have told PHP to `die()` if it doesn't.